# Test Strategy for the Reverse Sync process by using KAFKA

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, test-design, test-strategy

How can I test (Test Strategy) for the Reverse Sync process implemented by using KAFKA? Any inputs on this?

Detailed Flow: The data from Database 2 will be published into the KAFKA topic via the producer
which will be fetched by the consumer and stored into Database 1.

**How can this end to end flow be tested for bulk data?**

**Also is there any software which can track what data has been published into the topic?**

Comment: What risks are you trying to investigate in your testing?

Comment: @JoãoFarias - Here for bulk data testing I am considering scenarios where Redundancy Check, Data Mismatch Check, Duplicity check can be performed on the data consumed and stored into Database 1.